# Unable to embed tweet into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I am trying to embed a tweet into my website through [this method](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169559-embedding-a-tweet-on-your-website-or-blog).

But I am unable to get it right. This is my HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en">
  <p lang="en" dir="ltr">Can you answer this? Tem como calcular a diagonal no Canvas? <a href="http://t_.co/E8dD01jGKX">http://t_.co/E8dD01jGKX</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/javascript?src=hash">#javascript</a></p>
  &mdash; SO em Português (@StackOverflowPT) <a href="https://twitter.com/StackOverflowPT/status/613791039539806208">June 24, 2015</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And all I am seeing in browser is this:

[image]

Merely just HTML, not style as Twitter embedded tweet box.

Comment: What do you see in the console? Are you serving from the filesystem?

Comment: How do you test? Code you've posted [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/47gve0e4/).

Comment: I am getting this in console `GET file://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.` but if i access the path `//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js ` in browser i can get to the script file.

Comment: @sainaen: in browser, tried both in chrome and mozilla.

Comment: Try to replace `//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js` with `http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js`. It will make it work even if it's embedded in the local file (with the `file` scheme).

Comment: read their documentation https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets/javascript-create

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link to the Twitter's `widgets.js` is a so called protocol relative or scheme-less: it doesn't define its own [URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) and uses whatever its host page happend to be opened on. This is useful to support both `http` and `https` schemes without changing the link in the source code.

Now, because you're testing with the local file, the scheme used is `file`, that is [specifically created](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) for files located on the same machine with browser. And so protocol-less `//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js` gets the `file` scheme and becomes a link to the local file `widgets.js` in the folder `platform.twitter.com` which probably you don't have on your machine.

To fix that, just add a scheme, `http` or `https`, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en">
    <p lang="en" dir="ltr">Can you answer this? Tem como calcular a diagonal no Canvas? <a href="http://t.co/E8dD01jGKX">http://t.co/E8dD01jGKX</a>  <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/javascript?src=hash">#javascript</a>
    </p>
    &mdash; SO em Português (@StackOverflowPT) <a href="https://twitter.com/StackOverflowPT/status/613791039539806208">June 24, 2015</a>
  </blockquote>
  <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <!--                 ^                -->
</body>

</html>
```